# Storing the result of LARGE_INTEGER / LARGE_INTEGER

Tags: c++, performance, timer

I'm trying to develop a simple Timer class for a game I'm making. Right now, all this class does is calculate how long a frame is taking to render for some FPS calculations.

I am using Window's QueryPerformanceCounter function ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to get the highest possible resolution (I already got my computer's counter frequency via QueryPerformanceFrequency)

Here is my function for getting the last frame's time in seconds:

`void update_time()
{
    last = current;
    counter(&current);
    last_frame_time = current.QuadPart - last.QuadPart;
    last_frame_time_secs = last_frame_time / timer_frequency.QuadPart;
}`

Currently, last_frame_time_secs is a double variable. When I compile, I get a warning:

```
 warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'LONGLONG' to 'double', possible loss of data
```

and last_frame_time_secs is always 0.0. I assume this is because the result of the division is so small that doubles cannot store it? Is there any larger data structure I can use?

Comment: See: http://paste.rohitab.com/2862  specifically `LPCSTR GetCodeSpeed(CODESPEED *cs)` Not sure why it says dataloss since `long long` and `double` are both 8 bytes and there is no precision loss. Perhaps it meant the other way around..

Comment: @cantchooseusernames doubles use space for the exponent part, so less precision.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I completely forgot that doing integer division gets rid of the fractional part, no matter how you're storing it :) Changing the last line to this:

```
last_frame_time_secs = (double)last_frame_time / (double)timer_frequency.QuadPart;
```

fixed it.